# Create Matrix by Grouping - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a very large dataset and trying to develop a matrix to use for a visualization, but am running into issues with counting relationships. 
My data is structured like this:

```
| Project       | University |
|---------------|------------|
| Project One   | UniA       |
| Project One   | UniB       |
| Project One   | UniC       |
| Project Two   | UniC       |
| Project Two   | UniA       |
| Project Two   | UniB       |
| Project Two   | UniD       |
| Project Three | UniE       |
| Project Four  | UniA       |
| Project Four  | UniD       |
```

And I am trying to create a matrix like this:

```
|      | UniA | UniB | UniC | UniD | UniE |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| UniA | 0    | 2    | 1    | 2    | 0    |
| UniB | 2    | 0    | 2    | 1    | 0    |
| UniC | 1    | 2    | 0    | 1    | 0    |
| UniD | 2    | 1    | 1    | 0    | 0    |
| UniE | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    |
```

If the Uni does not have a relationship with any other Uni (UniE for example), I would like to ignore it from my final matrix.

I am stuck on this one - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the logic to construct the matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do a `self-join` and use `pd.crosstab` with `reindex`:

```
#do a self-join and eliminate same row matches
dfm = df.merge(df, on='Project').query('University_x != University_y')

#get unique universities
lu = df['University'].unique()

#create a crosstab report and reindex to fill zeroes
pd.crosstab(dfm['University_x'], dfm['University_y'])\
  .reindex(index=lu, columns=lu, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
University_y  UniA  UniB  UniC  UniD  UniE
University_x                              
UniA             0     2     2     2     0
UniB             2     0     2     1     0
UniC             2     2     0     1     0
UniD             2     1     1     0     0
UniE             0     0     0     0     0
```

---

Don't want to see all zero rows/columns remove `reindex`:

```
pd.crosstab(dfm['University_x'], dfm['University_y'])
```

Output:

```
University_y  UniA  UniB  UniC  UniD
University_x                        
UniA             0     2     2     2
UniB             2     0     2     1
UniC             2     2     0     1
UniD             2     1     1     0
```

Comment: Thanks - that works perfectly! Do you happen to know how to remove rows or columns that are returning only 0  (e.g. UniE)?

Comment: Yes, remove the `.reindex` part.  I thought you might want those zeros.  If you remove that .reindex you will not see UniE.

Comment: Neat trick with the self join.  Was thinking `groupby` but this is definitely cleaner.

Comment: Awesome - this answers my question. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks @r.ook!  Happy coding, CodeQQ.